# Ввод данных на время

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос нубский, нужно сделать ввод на время, чтобы программа выполнила функцию и завершилась если ничего не было введено. Вот пример:

```
import threading
import _thread
note = None
def killall():
    _thread.interrupt_main()
def timer(note, seconds):   
    timer = threading.Timer(seconds, killall)
    try:
        timer.start()
        note = input('Note: ')
    except Exception:
        pass
    timer.cancel()
    return note
timer(note,10)
```

По истечению таймера функция выполняется, но программа не завершается, с _thread.exit() результат тот же.

Answer (score 1):

Для прерывания ввода можно использовать модуль `signal`:

```
import signal


def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutError()


signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)


def input_timer(note, timeout):
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    try:
        s = input("Note: ")
    except TimeoutError:
        print()
        return "Timeout"
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)
    return s

print(input_timer("Note: ", 5))
print(input_timer("Note 2: ", 10))
```